# Android write to file - can't find file

Tags: android

I am a newbie in Android development. I try to write something to a file.
I am using the code:

```
try {
                    FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(
                            "out.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

                    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                    osw.write("something");
                    osw.flush();
                    osw.close();
                    fOut.close();

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    Log.e("FILE WRITE ERROR", e.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("FILE WRITE ERROR", e.getMessage());
                }
```

Everything it's ok but I can't find the file in DDMS FIle Explorer. Could you help me and tell me where Android saves the file? It isn't in "/data/data/my_project_package".
Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

1) be sure to have this in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

2) It makes a difference, either testing with the emulator or the device. In case of the latter, be sure to unmount the device from your PC (Pick: "Only charging"). Debugging will still work that way. It's just that you cannot write and watch at the same time.

This method works:

```
public void writeToExternalStoragePublic(String filename, int content) {
    String packageName = this.getPackageName();
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/Android/data/" + packageName + "/files/";
    if (isExternalStorageAvailable() && !isExternalStorageReadOnly()) {
        try {
            boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
            if (!exists) {
                new File(path).mkdirs();
            }
            // Open output stream
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(path + filename,true);
            // write integers as separated ascii's
            fOut.write((Integer.valueOf(content).toString() + " ").getBytes());
            fOut.write((Integer.valueOf(content).toString() + " ").getBytes());
            // Close output stream
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using this code with the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`. I still get a `FileIOException (java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.foo/files/This.html: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied))`  in the `new FileOutputStream` line. What could I be missing? I'm running in the emulator. I note that `File(path).mkdirs()` does not throw any exception. It doesn't create the dirs either.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a lot of questions on this topic and the problem often seems to boil down to i) not requesting permissions in the `AndroidManifest.xml` ii) The device's storage being mounted to a computer at the time the app was being run or iii) emulator settings.

In the hope that others who have tried all these solutions and failed, I submit iv) computer decides to arbitrarily ignore your permission setting in `AndroidManifest.xml` after pulling code from a source repository that was written on another computer.  In my case I'd just written some code on Computer A that wrote to external storage.  I checked said code into source control and then pulled said code to Computer B.  When I reinstalled the app from Computer B onto the device, I started getting the Permission denied exception.

*The fix*: make *any* change to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file on Computer B (e.g. insert a newline somewhere).  This fixed the problem for me.  I don't know why.  It's probably one of the rarer cases, but more frustrating ones.

Answer (score 1):

Place `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE">` in your manifest.

[Here](http://www.chainfire.eu/articles/113/Is_Google_blocking_apps_writing_to_SD_cards_/) is a reference on it.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I didn't need to change the USB option to "Only Charging" and could keep it in "file transfer" mode. However, I did need to call a method to the Android Media Scanner to display this file.

[How to Run Media Scanner in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13270982/7152106)