# Android save images not update to gallery

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, gallery

I'm trying to save my images from ImageView to sd card and they are saving to sd card but they are not updating to gallery. Here is my code.

```
public void save(View v) {
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), backgrounds.get(currentPosition)) ;
    File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath()
    + "/Folder/");
    dir.mkdirs();
    String Image = System.currentTimeMillis()+".Png";
    File file = new File(dir, Image);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Saved to SD Card",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    try {
    output = new FileOutputStream(file);
    // Compress into png format image from 0% - 100%
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
    output.flush();
    output.close();
   }
    catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837485/how-can-i-update-the-android-gallery-after-a-photo

Comment: i will give it try if this will work for me or not

Answer (score 1):

You have to first add mime type to the image

it will work.

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
    context, 
    new String[]{ pathToFile1, pathToFile2 }, 
    new String[]{ "audio/mp3", "*/*" }, 
    new MediaScannerConnectionClient()
    {
        public void onMediaScannerConnected()
        {
        }
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri)
        {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you saved bitmap as PNG file in sdCard.
Make sure that Gallery knows that PNG file has been created.

```
Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
context.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```