# Update Gallery after capture an image android

Tags: android, image, android-camera-intent

I try to create an app that can capture image from camera and show the result based on image path. Inside the button which handles capturing image as below

```
btnImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Nama_foto_" + waktu + ".jpg");

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
                intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                getParentFragment().startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
            }catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
                //display an error message
                String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support capturing images!";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

And as a respon from camera capturing Im writing below code

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {

            performCrop();
        }
        else if(requestCode == PIC_CROP){
            //get the returned data
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            //get the cropped bitmap
            Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");

            picturePath = file.getAbsolutePath();

            try {
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thePic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, bytes);

                file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                out.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //retrieve a reference to the ImageView
            //ImageView picView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.picture);
            //display the returned cropped image
        imgView.setImageBitmap(thePic);
        }

        try {

        }catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Maaf gagal mengambil foto.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

}

Variable picturePath declared outside OnCreateView as an empty string.
The problem is, whenever I run the app and capture the image. The image didnt show immediately in the gallery but instead I need to rerun the app (thru android studio) to see the image in gallery. It seems like something inside oncreateview trigger the event. But I still cant figure out what.

Pls help me fix the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems that your question should be rephrased differently:
this may solve your problem

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(myNewFile)));
```

reference : 
[How can I update the Android Gallery after a photo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837485/how-can-i-update-the-android-gallery-after-a-photo)

Comment: I changed my question,,,where should I declare above code?

Comment: Tried ur code stil not showing/saved in android gallery. But in my app the image was shown

Comment: I was trying to give the folder path. It took me much time to discover this. It should be full path of image itself.