# File Hidden on Windows Explorer from my Android Device

Tags: android

I'm developping an Android app. This app generates a file on the \sdcard\ folder , but when I want to take it from the computer , i can't get it. The files appears on my device with Cabinet , but not on the computer.
What is the problem ?

Thanks for your answer.

EDIT : I run my app on a Nexus 7 with  KitKat 4.4.4 build.

Comment: reconnect your device to your pc

Comment: I tried , but it doesn't work , when i create a folder from my device,  it doesn't appear too. But I create a file or a folder in my device from the computer , it appears on the device file explorer.

Comment: The file will also not shown after you reconnect you device?

Comment: Nope , after that , i reboot the device , and it seems to work now , i can see the file , but if i create another one , i can't see it , i have to reboot each time i create a file.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Comment: Starting from Android 4.4, only System apps can now use it. I use Nexus 7 (2013) with 4.4.4 for my development.

Comment: Invoking the media scanner is what needs to happen, this was just a simple trick for doing it

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270789/how-to-run-media-scanner-in-android for an example of invoking it on a specific file