# Saving image in Gallery

Tags: java, android

I am taking a screenshot and saving it in storage with my application name. It's not giving any error and saving photo in storage, but it appears in the gallery after I restart my phone.

My save method for photo is like below:

```
public void saveQuoteImage(Bitmap quoteImage){
  Date now = new Date();
  android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);
  try {
    // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file

    String dirPath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+File.separator+"quotes_king";

    File dirFile=new File(dirPath);
    if(!dirFile.exists())dirFile.mkdirs();

    // String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";
    // create bitmap screen capture
    File imageFile = new File(dirFile.getPath()+File.separator+ now + ".jpg");

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    int quality = 100;
    quoteImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);

    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();

  } catch (Throwable e) {
    // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

What I am missing in this ?

Thanks

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @victorsosa Thanks for comment. its not giving any error but showing saved image only after restart my mobile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to tell at MediaScanner that your file exists.

Something like this:

```
public final void addManually(File file) {
        try{
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(mContext.getContentResolver(),
                    file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), null);
            mContext.sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,
                    Uri.fromFile(file))
            );
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should invoke the media scanner on the new file.

[how to run media scanner in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270789/how-to-run-media-scanner-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Use media scanner in android.Just add the code below.

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { imagefile.toString() }, null, null);
```