# How can songs from other apps be queried using a ContentResolver query call?

Tags: java, android

**Context**

I'm learning Android app development and to learn I thought I would build a music library app. I intend for the app initially to show songs from other apps on the device (then eventually moving onto playback). For example, on my phone there is music in both One Drive and Play Music. I would like to query both of their libraries.

**What I've Tried**

I uploaded a couple of songs (.mp3 & .flac) into the the `sdcard/Music` folder on the device. I ensured Play Music and Groove had populated music libraries.

```
public SongReader GetSongs()
{
    Cursor cursor = activity
        .getContentResolver()
        .query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    return new SongReader(cursor);
}
```

`SongReader` is a custom class designed to iterate over a `Cursor` and read custom `Song` objects.

**Problem**

No songs are returned from the query call. Using the debugger and evaluating `cursor.getCount()` returns `0` and `cursor.getColumns()` returns 27 values.

**Question**

How can the music libraries of other apps be queried?

*(Optional)* Why did the couple of songs I uploaded to the device not get returned in the query response?

*(Optional)* Is there any way, I can detect any app installed on the device that "exposes" a media library?

Comment: This might be a permission issue. Try adding `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to the app manifest. I don't think it'll query Play Music or One Drive, but it should at least find the files you added to sdcard/Music.

Comment: I have
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
in the AndroidManifest.xml file, so I'm a bit confused why it's not detecting them.

Comment: Have you run a media scan? Restart your device or [do it programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270789/how-to-run-media-scanner-in-android)

Comment: I'll implement a media scan button in the menu of the app tomorrow. Hopefully that works. I'm also interested in querying media from Play Music, maybe it exposes an api?

Comment: I restarted the device today and it found the songs and shows them in the list!